# Order and Disorder Operators in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, differential-geometry, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking

On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27t_Hooft_operator), the 't Hooft loop operator is called a "disorder parameter," in contrast to the Wilson loop operator, which is an "order parameter." From my limited knowledge of condensed matter physics, order parameters are synonymous with "coarse-grained quantum fields," so even the latter statement doesn't make sense.

I understand there is a geometric duality (namely, Hodge duality) between the two operators, but can someone elucidate the notion of order/disorder either through other physical examples or through more formal arguments in QFT?

Comment: The following review article on disorder operators by Fradkin is very nice: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.05780v2

Answer (score 1):

In critical phenomena *order parameter* is defined as a quantity that is zero in disordered phase and differs from zero in the ordered one. I suppose one can introduce *disorder* parameter in the same way.

Coarse-graining comes from a particular way of introducing order parameter, e.g., in the context of Landau theory of phase transitions. It does not necessarily have to do with quantum fields. I suggest Goldenfeld's [*Lectures on phase transitions and the renormalization group*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201554097) for a clear review of these concepts.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. Is the correct definition of a disorder parameter then a quantity that is zero in the ordered phase but nonzero in the disordered phase? Also, I read that such parameters can exhibit singular behavior. Do you mind explaining a bit about that?

Comment: @jsborne I wouldn't be surprised, if *disorder parameter* is t'Hooft's personal invention or a slang used in the subfield. Order parameter may be indeed singular at the transition point or have singular derivatives.

Comment: Using order / disorder to refer to these line operators is mostly historical.